# Dividing values of two SQL crosstabs

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, crosstab

I want to create two crosstab tables, and then take the ratios of the two to get a percentage. The first one looks like this:

```
TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfFees (Y/N)]
SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
FROM [Deal Data ECM]
WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Fees (Y/N)])="Y"))
GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];
```

and the second one should have everything the same, except Fees (Y/N) will be set ="N". Then I want to divide the corresponding values in each table. Is there a way to do this in one SQL expression?

EDIT:

let's imagine the result of query1 and 2 are as follows:

```
Query1
    Blue  Red
Cat  1     2
Dog  3     4

Query2
    Blue  Red
Cat  5     10
Dog  15    20

I want Query 3 to result in:

Query3
    Blue  Red
Cat  .5    .5
Dog  .5    .5
```

EDIT 2: That is what the data looks like. More specifically, the results of each query would look like this:

```
          Region1 Region2 Region3
Dealtype1 some numbers in each of these cells
Dealtype2
Dealtype3
```

I'm not sure why you need actual data, the example above would have the same solution sa this one (I just want to know the syntax, what SQL statements to use, etc)

SOLUTION:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(IIf([Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]="Y",1,0))/Count([Disclosed Fees (Y/N)]) AS percent_fees_disclosed
SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
FROM [Deal Data ECM]
GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];
```

Comment: Let us *not* imagine any such thing. That is not what the results of a crosstab look like. If you cannot solve this problem using the query design window and do not wish to provide actual sample data, create a dummy table and two crosstabs and paste the results from them.

Comment: You have left out the important point, which is what is the column that contains cat, dog called? It is on this column that you need to join, hence the comment above.

Comment: Also, you will learn more about how the whole thing works if you use the query design window and two simple crosstabs, as I described below.

Comment: see the edit above. the reason i am not doing this in design view is because eventually i want it to be automated (i don't want to have 3 separate queries cluttering up my Queries), and so I want to have the SQL for all of them down. I don't think you can do more than one query at a time in design view.

Comment: Okay. I am failing to explain. You must join query 1 to query 2 on a column. You cannot have crosstabs as subqueries, but you can use two crosstab query to create a third query that joins the two crosstab queries on the common column. While you can create these queries in VBA, you will have to create at least two queries, that is use createqdf. I do this often enough, and I find creating the three queries useful,  cont ...

Comment: cont ... but this type of thing is only suitable for data analysis, not for user interaction or production. Designing in the window will allow you to understand the sql required. Finally, if you look at your examples, none of them show the common column.

Comment: ok, i think i understand. even if it doesn't allow for user interaction, i would still like to use it for analysis. what would the SQL syntax of the third query be? or, if you prefer (i think this would be more difficult), how do i join these two crosstab queries on a column, and then produce the result that i want? i'm just not sure that this is as difficult as we're making it out to be -- it's just looking at two tables, and dividing values of one by the corresponding values of the other to generate a new table of proportions -- if this was any other language, it would be 3 lines of code.

Comment: It is not difficult at all. You are not providing the required information and you are not using the query design window.

Comment: can you tell me one more time exactly what information you need??? the last edit above is _exactly_ what the output of both crosstabs is, except with numbers in the cells. i don't see how having the exact numbers would help you, since the results of a query are variable anyways.

Comment: There is no column heading for the common column. BTW you do know that people are not paid to answer questions on forums and it is not their job? People answer questions for a variety of reasons, but they are not obliged to answer in any way.

Comment: i ended up figuring it out. see the edit above.

Comment: Well done. I am glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a third query based on the two crosstabs joined on deal type.

In the query design window, create Query1:

```
TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfFees1]
SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
FROM [Deal Data ECM]
WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Fees (Y/N)])="Y"))
GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];
```

Next, create Query2:

```
TRANSFORM Count([Deal Data ECM].[Fees (Y/N)]) AS [CountOfFees2]
SELECT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
FROM [Deal Data ECM]
WHERE ((([Deal Data ECM].[Fees (Y/N)])="N"))
GROUP BY [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Type]
PIVOT [Deal Data ECM].[Deal Region];
```

Finally, create Query3:

```
SELECT Query1.[DealRegion1], Query2.[DealRegion1], 
       Query2.[DealRegion2], Query1.[DealRegion2]
FROM Query1 
INNER JOIN Query2 
ON Query1.[Deal Type] = Query2.[Deal Type];
```

You can drag a field from one table or query to the next to create a join. INNER JOIN only includes records where both fields match.

Further information:

[Fundamentals of Relational Database Design, Paul Litwin, 2003](http://r937.com/relational.html)

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: do you think you could explain (or link to somewhere where it explains) exactly how to do this? i'm very new to sql.

Comment: Okay, some sql and some notes. Do not forget that one of the strengths of MS Office products is that they interact rather well, so you can use Excel quite easily with Access.

Comment: thanks again, i'm still confused though.. there is no DealRegion1 and DealRegion2, just one DealRegion. imagine entry 1,1 in the table resulting from the first query is 5, and entry 1,1 in the table resulting from the second query is 10, i want my result to be .5 (5/10).

Comment: I cannot see the results of your crosstabs, so all I can do is give you an example. When you join on the field that both cross tab have in common, you should put the various fields into the query design grid by dragging or double-clicking.  DealRegion1 and DealRegion2 are just my guesses at whatever deal regions you have. It should all become clear to you when you add the crosstabs to the query design window.

Comment: i'm still trying to do it in just the SQL, since design view isn't working for me. i'm just not sure where the division will happen in the join -- One I have two resulting pivot tables, how do i divide each element in the first one by the corresponding element in the second one?

Comment: What do you mean design view is not working for you? Have you created a third query that includes the results from cross tab 1 and cross tab 2? If you are not familiar with sql, you can use tha query as the basis of a report.

Comment: i don't think we are on the same page about what i'm trying to do. the first two queries you gave me are correct, but the third one isn't. i'm not all that familiar with sql, so i don't know how to structure the third query, but here's a pseudocode way of stating what i want my result to be: --Table result3; --for row in numRows(resultOfQuery1) --for col in numCols(resultOfQuery1) --result3[row][col] = resultOfQuery1[row][col]/resultOfQuery2[row][col] does that make sense?

Comment: I cannot give you details for the third query because you have not posted results from crosstab 1 and crosstab 2, which means I am guessing. I said this a few comments ago.